# Reason to not use boats when there is a is river

Tags: technology, magic, travel, rivers

In my fantasy world, there is a massive river that flows through the heart of the empire. This river is used for obtaining potable water as well as feeding crops, however, boating is strictly prohibited. I have linked this with a belief in the religion of the empire that the water symbolizes the deity's blood, and thus it would be disrespectful to use it as a way of transport. However, with as with most religions, things like this are created from real-life reasons that they cannot understand, and thus will blame them on the god, so, my question is, what would this be (the real-life reason, that is)? So, why would boating be unsafe or not useful?

Comment: Are there any beasts lurking below in the water?

Comment: @Alexander That is up for interpretation, but I would rather a different reason if that is okay for plot's sake.

Comment: How this is not an idea generation? Please provide with details of your river or society. For now VTC for opinion-based AND too broad.

Comment: maybe [this](https://www.thepetitionsite.com/takeaction/239/515/979/), perhaps [this](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2966974/Manhattan-encased-ice-deep-freeze-intense-Polar-Vortex-Hudson-turned-river-ice-record-lows.html)

Comment: @Vylix I do not think it is too broad. It takes a **very good** reason for people not to use water transport when a "massive river" is available. That narrows it down enough IMHO. Maybe enough to avoid being "idea generation" or "opinion based" even? I do not see urgent need to close this, in any case.

Comment: kind of weird that your empire can still retain control the other side of such river..

Comment: I recommend you to add restricting information, such as "the boats will always get destroyed, before the belief spread. So, what can make these boats get destroyed?"

Comment: @@Vylix I would, but that is not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for reasons they would not boat. The saftey of the boats is a very likely answer, but it could be others as well.

Comment: Vylix is correct, this is too broad and primarily opinion based.  The reason for this is that you're not asking us for reasons why people won't boat --- they already have one: a religious proscription.  You're asking us for the kernel of truth that justifies the religious proscription.  That's a fishing-for-ideas question and they're off-topic without providing us the rules and structure of your world.

Comment: @JBH I do not see the distinction. The two are only different if you assume that the religious proscription might be the original cause for not boating instead of simply the explanation for the actual cause, but the question does not make sense with that assumption. It is clear IMHO that the question is for the actual cause for not boating **and** the proscription that *follows* as "collective memory".

Comment: @VilleNiemi, Look at it this way: if the difference between the selected answer and all the other ansewrs is the quality of the answer, the question was on-topic.  If there is no difference between the quality of the answers and one was selected because the OP liked it better than the others, it's off-topic.  In this specific case, the river being filled with dead tree stumps and the river being filled with alligators are answers of equal quality.  Hence, fishing for ideas, hence, off-topic.

Comment: @VilleNiemi, let me give you a real example. I personally do not drink alcohol for religious reasons. If I told you nothing more and asked you to provide "real reasons" why I shouldn't drink alcohol you could (and would) come up with a proverbial thousand answers, none of which are better than any other. If I told you just one fact, which religion I belong to, it would narrow those reasons from one-thousand to one. That's why we don't permit fishing-for-answers questions without knowing the rules of the world. Most of the answers would be without value, and we want the site to provide value.

Comment: @JBH First example, the reason those are of equal quality is that they both are bad. For **any** question it is possible to generate answers of equal quality by making bad answers, so this example is worthless. You do have a point, but you are simply **assuming** answers can't be objectively better for this question, not proving it. Second example, drinking alcohol is not particularly useful, water transport is. You do not need a good reason to not drink alcohol, any reason will do. Same is not true of people living along a massive river not using boats.

Comment: @VilleNiemi There is still no objective way to pick a best answer. I could say that they don't use boats because they had little wood early on and mainly used stone so never really developed boats or I could say that they were raided by people in boats so decided boats were unholy. Which is better? There is no objective way to pick, the only way is to chose which answer you prefer (subjective).

Comment: @Bellerophon Those are still only equal by virtue of being bad answers. Look, I don't really disagree that it is unclear if this question could have "a best answer", I am just not conviced by the arguments I have seen for it not having one. There is a large grey area between "not having clear answer" and "not being obvious if there is a clear answer" and in worldbuilding it is very common to give the benefit of doubt in such cases, so I am simply puzzled why not this time.

Comment: @VilleNiemi There is no way to judge a best answer. Site policy is to close it. If people are given the benefit of the doubt in other cases it is because they either gave a clearer means of deciding a best answer or because the site policy was misapplied.

Comment: @Bellerophon Again, how do you **know** there is no way to judge the best answer? It really bothers me that people seem absolutely certain of that, but when they try to explain to me why they are so certain, they do so by supplying two bad answers and pointing out it is impossible to say which is less bad. Again, that is true for all questions. What is relevant for rules is whether good answers can be ranked in some reasonable manner.

Comment: @Bellerophon  And the thing is, this question has several criteria which could be used to rank answers. Would it make people stop boating? How permanent would it be? Would it reasonably be transformed to a religious prescription? Is there a reason people think it is the blood of their God? Is a reason supplied to think the river is holy? Is there a way for the to empire span both sides of the river without boats? And those are just the ones that occurred to me while writing my answer. Many questions nobody complains about come with fewer criteria, which is why I am puzzled and annoying people.

Comment: @villieNiemi That is basically a list of requirements, some of which aren't actually needed. The op doesn't ask why they think it is a god's blood or how they keep control of both sides of the river. All they ask is why the river wouldn't be used for sailing. If the question did have all those requirements it might not be too opinion based though that's not a guarenteed. It would depend on how it was written.

Comment: @Bellerophon Sorry, did not see the comment before. Requirements are needed to see if an answer is valid. Criteria are used for ranking answers. But that was really pretty insigtful comment from you as I think you spotted the key issue here. While people were driving me crazy with unsubstantiated claims of it being impossible to rank answers and choose the best one, all the examples and arguments really **were** about there being lots of equally **valid** answers. And rules don't really help either as they do assume that validity equals quality as it does for most subject matters.

Answer (score 11):

The actual reason they think the river water is the blood of their God, is because it is bright red. The reason for that is [cyanobacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanobacteria). These are endemic to the chain of lakes that the river originates from. The cyanobacteria  are toxic and the toxin is volatile enough that boating will result in the people involved feeling the wrath of the God in their bodies.

This would require the people not to drink the blood of the God without boiling or some other preparation that removes the bacteria and cleanses the toxin. A closed vessel in full sunlight for few hours would probably be enough. This contradicts the question about potability, but requiring people to do a ritual before drinking what they think of as the blood of their God is reasonable IMHO.

Interestingly the most likely reason for the bacteria being red would be that the light they get is green. This would be most likely because the river is overgrown with plants. Lots a narrow and shallow channels overgrown with trees. Water filled with reeds and water plants such as water lilies. Slow moving water and verdant life. Very pretty and abundant. Like a green natural cathedral for your God.

It would also be a pain to navigate with boats of any size which would supply an explanation why the people do not want to use water transport. You'd need to create artificial channels for that and with the toxins in the water all your workers would probably die soon after starting work on that sacrilege.

An added bonus is that the cyanobacteria can fix nitrogen meaning the water would come with fertilizer ready. So the plants on the river and on the fields irrigated with the river water would get an extra boost. If you have occasional or seasonal floods leaving river mud on your fields that mud will be very fertile. A blessing from God.

Only real downside is that the toxin would probably kill all the fish and water birds. But, if you do not want boats, you probably do not want a thriving fishing economy either. The river would be eerily silent, sacred.

EDIT:
One added benefit of this solution. As mentioned in comments it would be very difficult for the empire to retain control of the both sides of a massive river without boats. **Unless** the river is divided into multiple channels narrow enough to bridge over. This solution already has that for other reasons.

Comment: I would suggest that a few plants and animals have adapted to the toxins in the water. They would however be toxic to consume and would therefore be sacred (messengers) of the god. The people have not adapted due to their ability to cleanse the water before drinking. Bridge-building would be a perilous business for the same reason boating would be though.

Comment: If the river was red and dead then the people wouldn't have settled near it, the point of having a river is good water, fishing and transport. We're taking one away, taking away the other two means no town.

Comment: @Separatrix The point of a river is that the land along it grows more food than other lands. This difference can be rather large especially in ancient times before soil quality has dropped. Also even if the river water itself was undrinkable (it isn't in my answer as the ritual is simple) this is where all the clean water in the area flows to.

Comment: @Rissiepit I am assuming plants have no issues with the water. I am assuming individual river channels might be narrow enough to bridge over without building anything in the water, but I agree it would probably still be dangerous.

Answer (score 11):

#### Lost History.

In the ancient past, the river separated two kingdoms. They were not terribly expansive, just some miles of shore on each side, so they did not need the river for shipping. After a few costly but indecisive wars, they had a truce which included no boating of any kind on the river. A boat on the river meant an attack in progress.

Rather than try to explain the complicated truce to illiterate and child-like peasants, both sides invented the religious myth together and told it as new revealed wisdom, part of the actual religion about the river being the life blood of the creator. Just a new twist on that: The creator recently sent us a memo, it said "I hate boats!"

The kings passed away, the truce held, their successors passed away, and eventually revolutions, coups, assassinations and so on. After many centuries the actual truce was long turned to ash, but the nature of the agreement held, and the religion and its proscription against boats held as well.

Nobody knows why God hates boats, but it says so, right here in the Bible, and this Bible is over a thousand years old, so show it some respect. Even if you built the boats, nobody is going to set foot on 'em. Because even if they float, they're still going to hell when they die.

Answer (score 9):

My first thoughts are related to the current. If this massive river has a strong current and (say) some jagged rocks, reefs or other dangers to boats lurking just below the surface, the first attempts to put a boat on it could have resulted in disaster. In such a case, if the religious belief was beginning to form around the river already, a priest points to drowning people who can't be reached (again, because of the current) and says 'See! Our God rejects our attempts to travel through his lifestreams!'

The agrarian population all nod sagely and agree, and the proscription is born.

The only problem with this is that a long-existent river would have worn down such obstructions under its own current over time, so the timing of the creation of the river itself and the 'accidents' would have to be somewhat close. That may fit however, because a people dying of thirst who see first a trickle, then a stream, then a raging river over the space of a few years may well accept the original formation of this river as an act of a deity instead of a simple change in climate and weather patterns.

Answer (score 7):

In New Zealand there are plenty of rivers, but relatively few that people can boat on. Why? Most of them look like this for most of their length:
[image]
(Image from https://www.owenriverlodge.co.nz/ )

Quite frankly, you couldn't boat on that with "normal" boats if you tried! But jet boats were designed in NZ in 1954 and now we can travel on the rivers:
[image]
 (Image from http://www.hamiltonmarine.co.nz/hamiltonjet_nz/hjnz_jet_boats.html)

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn3lOtabSNo

However, the water is (or used to be) potable.

This leaves you completely free to figure out why the villages think it's a deity without wondering why they can't boat on it. They can't boat on it because of the geology of the environment.

Comment: With this reason, you could have some "chosen" persons who are able to travel the river - might be nice for storytelling

Comment: I wonder how large that river could get, and for how long it could flow, without erosion digging in and providing a clear navigable channel. Still, I really like the idea of the river simply having really shallow portions at such regular intervals that navigation is just not possible in anything bigger than a draft.

Comment: These river beds have looked like that for millenia, and some are pretty massive. Some of the bigger ones (eg the Waimakariri) are more navigable, but still only by modern boats and adrenaline junkies on rafts.... NZ is geologically young, but we're still talking eons before erosion wears them down to more continental style rivers.

Answer (score 4):

The joys of religion mean that the reason doesn't have to be entirely logical, but should be based on something logical if you dig deep enough.

> And it was, that a man tried to cross the river on a boat. And it was a beautiful calm day and the river was quiet. And it happened that as he approached the middle of the river, god sent a vast wave which swallowed him and he was drowned. And the priests said, no man shall again put a boat on the river, such is the judgement of god. And every month when the moon is full, god sends the wave and the water turns to salt, to remind us that his river is holy.

*All hail the patriarchy.*

Let me introduce the [Severn Bore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8TeguB3BYo), these days mostly used by surfers, but such a thing could easily be the judgement of god for those who dare to use boats on the holy river.

Your river is only tidal on spring tides, so mostly flows fresh, but the particular combination of tide and current mean that you get a large tidal bore on those tides. The fact that the rest of the time it's perfectly safe to take a boat on the river notwithstanding, to do so is heresy and punishable by drowning by the priests if the wave of god doesn't take you.